# Why my cache gets empty after I reload the page in offline mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a PWA with react.js. I implemented the service worker for caching data but after I reload the page in offline mode the cache is empty.

I added The service worker and a few images below

```
 const CACHE_NAME = "version-1";
const urlsToCache = 

[ 
    'index.html', 
    'offline.html',
    'assets/icons/archive.svg', 
    'assets/icons/arrow-left.svg',
    'assets/icons/arrow-top.svg',   
];

const self = this;


self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then((cache) => {
                console.log('Opened cache');

                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
    )
});

// Listen for requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(() => {
                return fetch(event.request) 
                    .catch(() => caches.match('offline.html'))
            })
    )
});


self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    const cacheWhitelist = [];
    cacheWhitelist.push(CACHE_NAME);

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
                if(!cacheWhitelist.includes(cacheName)) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }
            })
        ))
            
    )
});
```

[image: Screenshot from online mode with cache]

Thank you for helping

Comment: Because that's how it works.  Your Javascript is part of that page.  When you reload the page, it clears out all the code and variables and starts over with a clean slate.  It's like running a console application two times in a row.

Comment: @TimRoberts service workers are saved in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the return statement on the caches.match('offline.html). I had the exact same problem myself. Took me a while to find the issue in my own code. Your anonymous func handling the catch needs to return the result of that match lookup. You're correctly returning the fetch call, in this scenario the catch result will be returned all the way up to the respondWith.

Another issue to call your attention to, is that I believe the examples out there using cache first design are unappealing. I think we want to rely on network fetching so that our PWAs will load the latest version of all our files. Yours sort of does this except that you are pre-caching during install which I advise against (except definitely need to pre-cache offline.html) and you're not dynamically caching. I just came up with a network first caching code that I just tested and believe it is ideal. Test it thoroughly but I think my code works such that we will always prefer network result and only when that fails we do cache lookup.
Note my addition of

```
else if (event.request.mode === 'navigate')
```

Which means we'll only return that offline.html page if the request is a navigation request.

```
const MAIN_CACHE = 'main-v3';
const OFFLINE_PAGE = '/offline.html';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...', event);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(MAIN_CACHE)
            .then(function(cache) {
                console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
                cache.add([
                    OFFLINE_PAGE
                ]);
                
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
            .then(function(keyList) {
                return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
                    if (key !== MAIN_CACHE) {
                        console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
                        return caches.delete(key);
                    }
                }));
            })
    );
    return self.clients.claim();
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    var url = event.request.url;
    console.log('[Service Worker] Fetching something ....', url, '\n', event);

    event.respondWith(
        //network first
        fetch(event.request)
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log('Loaded from web: ' + url);
                if (event.request.method === 'GET' &&
                        !url.startsWith('chrome-extension') &&
                        !url.includes('extension') &&
                        (url.startsWith('http'))) {
                    // Clone the response right after receiving it
                    var clonedRes = res.clone();
                    // Use the cloned response for caching
                    caches.open(MAIN_CACHE)
                        .then(function(cache) {
                            cache.put(url, clonedRes);
                        })
                }
                return res;
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.error(err + ' while fetching: ' + url);
                //look for it in the cache
                return caches.match(url)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (response) {
                            console.log('Loaded from cache: ' + url);
                            return response;
                        } else if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') { 
                            //if the request is a navigation request that is not in the cache, return the offline page
                            console.log('Redirecting to offline page from: ' + url);
                            return caches.open(MAIN_CACHE)
                                .then(function(cache) {
                                    return cache.match(OFFLINE_PAGE);
                            });
                        }
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        console.error('FAILED: ' + err + ' ' + url);
                    })
            })
    );
});
```